# INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT in Android not working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, auto-increment

I have the following code:

```
package com.example.mayur.myapplication;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class dbhandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="database1.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME= "Database";
    private static final String _ID="_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_NAME="Name";
    private static final String COLUMN_TITLE="Title";




    public dbhandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +" (_ID  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,COLUMN_Name TEXT, COLUMN_Title TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(query);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TABLE_NAME");
            onCreate(db);
    }
    public void addproduct(Database database)
    {
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_TITLE,database.get_title());
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME,database.get_name());        
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();

    }
    public void deleteproduct(String name)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db =getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_NAME + "=\"" + name + "\"; ");
    }

    public ArrayList<Database> load()
    {
        Database d=new Database();
        ArrayList<Database> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
        String query="SELECT * FROM " +  TABLE_NAME + " WHERE 1";
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery(query,null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
        {
            d.set_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name")));
            d.set_title(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Title")));
            ret.add(d);
            c.moveToNext();

                Log.d("id", "load: "+ ret.get(i).get_id());
        }
        db.close();

        return rSQLt;
    }
}
```

logd always shows id=0 inside the load method for all the iterations. I have also tried removing autoincrement but it doesn't work because every time I try to print data from SQLite database it always prints the last entry. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the `_id` in your object `d` -

Add this line in your `for loop`  -

```
d.set_id(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_ID")));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your column names do not match between the time you are creating your database and when you are inserting into it. so there is two solutions:

Either change these variables:

```
private static final String COLUMN_NAME="COLUMN_Name";
private static final String COLUMN_TITLE="COLUMN_Title";
```

or Change your code in `onCreate`:

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +" (_ID  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+COLUMN_Name+" TEXT, "+COLUMN_Title+" TEXT)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that it's your issue but AUTOINCREMENT isn't needed to have an auto incrementing field. In fact in most cases coding AUTOINCREMENT is disadvantageous in that it introduces unnecessary overheads. AUTOINCREMENT actually means to make that column unique within the entire database.

Here's the summary of AUTOINCREMENT from [Autoincrement In SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

> Summary
>
> ```
> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It
> ```
>
> is usually not needed.
>
> ```
> In SQLite, a column with type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is an alias for the ROWID (except in WITHOUT ROWID tables) which is always a 64-bit
> ```
>
> signed integer.
>
> ```
> On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an
> ```
>
> unused integer, usually one more than the largest ROWID currently in
>   use. This is true regardless of whether or not the AUTOINCREMENT
>   keyword is used.
>
> ```
> If the AUTOINCREMENT keyword appears after INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, that changes the automatic ROWID assignment algorithm to prevent the
> ```
>
> reuse of ROWIDs over the lifetime of the database. In other words, the
>   purpose of AUTOINCREMENT is to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs from
>   previously deleted rows.